# Jboss-4.0.5 Run.bat error ? (OS=Windows XP)

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, java, jboss

wehen I execute the Run.bat file in Jboss-4.0.5 the following error appear :-

`Error: no server JVM at C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll'.
Press any key to continue . . .`

I download JDK1.5.0_22

on other hand

what is I should change to make run.bath tacke this path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22` instade of tacke `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll`

Comment: jre6 = Java Runtime Environment 1.6; JRE1.6 != JDK1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your JAVA_HOME, it could be pointing to the JRE instead of an SDK. Also, close and reopen your command prompt window to "flush".